# How do I send multiple users message using a gridview with templates

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, gridview

How do I send mltiple users message using a griview which should be connected to two tables namely login(from where usernames will be retrieved and shown) and then the second table message (where a message is to be stored for particular usernames). I have connected it to login but I am not able to insert values into message table. Message table has msg_id , username and message columns.

Here is the design:

.aspx

```
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder2" Runat="Server">
<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    EnableModelValidation="True" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
    onrowcommand="GridView2_RowCommand">
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="username" HeaderText="username" 
        SortExpression="username" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="password" HeaderText="password" 
        SortExpression="password" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="utype" HeaderText="utype" SortExpression="utype" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="ptype" HeaderText="ptype" SortExpression="ptype" />
</Columns>
      </asp:GridView>
      <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:AutomobileConnectionString14 %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [login] WHERE ([utype] LIKE '%' + @utype + '%')">
        <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="U" Name="utype" Type="String" />
        </SelectParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
</asp:Content>
```

aspx.cs code

```
protected void GridView2_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName.Equals("cc"))
    {
        TextBox txt1 = (TextBox)GridView2.FooterRow.FindControl("TextBox1");
        foreach(GridView gr in GridView2.Rows)
        {
            CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)gr.FindControl("CheckBox1");
            if (chk.Checked)
            {
                Object ob = GridView2.DataKeys[gr.RowIndex].Value;

            }
```

now I am stuck her how can I insert values into other table message when it is already connected to Login table. Help me what I want to accomplish here is send message to checked users.

Comment: Have you defined the CommandName="cc" in gridview? The way you accomplishing is not right.

Comment: yes i did in the button tag i have given the command name="cc".

Comment: Are you want to insert messages into the message table when some checkedbox checked and button submitted? right?

Comment: yeah yeah ryt i hav been tryin so many days help me i have to give an assignment tomorrow

Comment: Ok wait for a while....

Comment: ok.. the thing is I want to send message to multiple users on their page if there is an alternative way i'll try it too .

Comment: Have you to show one message or multiple to one user?

Comment: What I need to do is whichever number of checkbox I select in the itemtemplate and then the message that I write in the textbox in the footertemplate of the griview That message should be stored in the table messages with their usernames and message.

Answer (score 0):

Try below :

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataKeyNames="userId"
        OnRowCommand="GridView2_RowCommand" OnRowEditing="GridView2_RowEditing" OnRowUpdated="GridView2_RowUpdated" OnRowUpdating="GridView2_RowUpdating">
        <Columns>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Username">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("username") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="password" HeaderText="password"
                SortExpression="password" />

            <asp:BoundField DataField="utype" HeaderText="utype" SortExpression="utype" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ptype" HeaderText="ptype" SortExpression="ptype" />

            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("messgae") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                 <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtMsg" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
           <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chk" runat="server" />
                </ItemTemplate>

            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>

    </asp:GridView>
```

On RowDataBound event to set the edit textbox for message by find control.
And refer to code for inline editing on check box click.

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/9f0ae2/gridview-edit-delete-and-update-in-Asp-Net/
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23471/Editable-GridView-in-ASP-NET